# How to explicitly fail a test case with Coded-UI

Tags: c#, testing, coded-ui-tests

I am automating some test cases with Coded-UI And I am trying to figure out how to explicitly fail a test case from the code instead of waiting for the code to timeout. I considered creating an assertion that is bound for failure, but that feels sloppy to me. Here is an example of my code:

```
public bool CheckifFileExists(String SearchFile, int secondswait)
    {
        bool FileExists = File.Exists(SearchFile);
        int i = 0;
        while (FileExists == false && i <= secondswait)
        {
            FileExists = File.Exists(SearchFile);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            i++;
        }

        return (FileExists);
    }


bool FileExistsStatus = CheckifFileExists(SearchFile, secondswait);

if(FileExistsStaus == true)
    //continue test case
else
    //explicitly fail test case
```

I looked around for a while but could not find anything specific to Coded-UI that allows me to fail the test case.

Thank you!

Comment: Why does Assert False feel sloppy to you?

Comment: That is what the assert is for in unit testing.  Not familiar with Coded-UI.  why would it be different there?

Comment: I just get the feeling that there is a better way to fail the test case, like in other applications like winrunner you have tl_step. If there is no better way with Coded-UI then I might just do the assertion method.

Comment: How about Assert.IsTrue(FileExistsStatus)?

Comment: That works perfectly for me stoj. It even helped me with another issue where I was trying to write to the Error Message. So now my code looks like this 

Assert.IsFalse(FileExistsStatus, "The installation failed");

Comment: A coded UI test fails whenever an unhandled exception is encountered in your `[TestMethod]`. So, why don't you throw a `FileNotFoundException` when a file is not found in your `CheckifFileExists` method? That would automatically fail your test, except when you want it to not exist, then you can catch the exception. You could also perform the `Assert.IsTrue` stoj is mentioning, or just explicitly throw an `Exception` in your `else` block.

Comment: @stoj I think you comment is perfect answer. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: You shouldn't use `System.String`, always use `string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moved from my comment on the question to an answer.

How about `Assert.IsTrue(FileExistsStatus)`?